# 'controltovalidate' error in IE8

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm getting a JavaScript error (in IE only of course) and I can't figure out why.  I assumed it was a trailing comma or something but I can't find one.  I'm hoping I'm overlooking something and maybe one of you can see what I missed.

My control and custom validator:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" MaxLength="100" CssClass="styled" Columns="50" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvName" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid contact name or email address" ControlToValidate="txtName" Display="None" ValidationGroup="PlatformContact" ClientValidationFunction="doesUserExist" />
                                <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceName" runat="server" TargetControlID="cvName" WarningIconImageUrl="~/img/icons/ic_asterisk.gif" CssClass="validatorStyled" PopupPosition="Right" CloseImageUrl="~/img/icons/ic_x_close_orange.png" />                                    
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valName" ErrorMessage="Enter a contact name or email address" ControlToValidate="txtName" Display="None" ValidationGroup="PlatformContact" />
                                <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceNameRequired" runat="server" TargetControlID="valName" WarningIconImageUrl="~/img/icons/ic_asterisk.gif" CssClass="validatorStyled" PopupPosition="Right" CloseImageUrl="~/img/icons/ic_x_close_orange.png" />
```

And here is the JavaScript/jQuery I am using:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var userExists = true;

    function doesUserExist(source, args) {
        var txtName = $('#<%= txtName.ClientID %>').val();
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: "{name:'" + txtName + "'}",
            url: "ManageMyContacts.aspx/DoesUserExist",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                userExists = result.d;
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //Something bad happened,redirect to login page
                window.location.href = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx") %>';
            }
        });
        args.IsValid = userExists;
    }
</script>
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  JavaScript error

> Message: 'controltovalidate' is null or not an object

Here is the WebMethod I user to check for the user name (in the code behind)

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static bool DoesUserExist(string name)
    {
        ManageMyContactsService service = new ManageMyContactsService();
        int index = name.IndexOf("[") + 1;
        if (index > 0)
        {
            string email = name.Substring(index, name.Length - (index + 1));
            return service.DoesUserExist(email);
        }
        else if (name.IndexOf("@") == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return service.DoesUserExist(name);
    }
```

I noticed the doesUserExist function gets called twice for some reason, can anyone tell why from this code?

Comment: Can you post the javascript error, and approx what line it happens on, if you have found that out?

Comment: Not related probably, but your code will also not work as expected because `userExists` is `undefined` when `args.IsValid = userExists` runs because ajax is asynchronous. Your code looks valid, i suspect the error you are getting is either C# related or something else.

Comment: @KevinB maybe it is related, can't remember how asp.net checks but if it isn't either true or false, it might struggle..

Comment: The reason i think it's asp is because of the error `"controltovalidate"` is an attribute of `asp:CustomValidator`. I don't know enough about asp to go further on that.

Comment: Also unrelated, you probably want to take `ValidateEmptyText="true"` off of the CustomValidator - you have the RequiredFieldValidator already and no point checking if username "" exists

Comment: I set userExists= true near the top, but there's some other js that wasn't relevant so I didn't include it (since the error is from this one function.)  I removed ValidateEmptyText since it was pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears an UpdatePanel was causing the second ajax call and was causing IE to throw a JS error.  Worked fine in the other browsers but not IE7/8!

Hope that helps someone with a similar issue.